# SSRS report manager blank

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 10.0.1600.22 installed on the server. When i try browse  http ://ssrsreports/reports
   it directs to 
    http ://ssrsreports/Pages/Folder.aspx which just shows a blank page. I am using IE 9. What i should se is the Reports manager.

However, if i browse 
    http ://ssrsreports/reportserver i see  basic page with list of directories and the SSRS version at the bottom.

Any help, do i need to switch on anything to view reports manager.

Answer (score 0):

Someone had changed the folder from /reports to /ReportsManager. I am now able to see the SSRS Reports Managaer interface.